# Show AlertDialog after clicking on a listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-alertdialog

I have a `SQLite` database. I am fetching data from database and showing it in `ListView`.

Now I need to create an `AlertDialog` box that appears after pressing on a `ListView` item. `AlertDialog` should show all information about that item.

I am able to open an `AlertDialog` after pressing on a `ListView` item, but it shows nothing.

What might be the problem?

Here's my Main2Activity:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

DBHelper myDb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main2);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    myDb = new DBHelper(this);

    //populate an ArrayList<String> from the database and then view it
    ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor data = myDb.getAllData();
    if(data.getCount() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "There are no contents in this list!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        while(data.moveToNext()){
            theList.add(data.getString(1));
            ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,theList);
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    Cursor res = myDb.getSingleData(buffer.toString());
                    while (res.moveToNext()) {
                        buffer.append("Url: " + res.getString(1) + "\n");
                        buffer.append("Name: " + res.getString(2) + "\n");
                    }

                    showMessage("Data",buffer.toString());

                }
            });
        }
    }
}

public void showMessage(String title,String Message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(Message);
    builder.show();
}
}
```

Here's my DBHelper.java

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "websites.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "website_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "id";
public static final String COL_2 = "url";
public static final String COL_3 = "command";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +"(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,url TEXT,command TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
//insert data
public boolean insertData(String url, String command){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,url);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,command);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
    if (result == -1){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
//RETRIEVE ALL DATA for listview
public Cursor getAllData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME; Cursor res = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return res;
}

//RETRIEVE SINGLE DATA FOR AlertDialog
public Cursor getSingleData(String url){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_2 + " = \"" + url + "\""; Cursor res = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return res;
}
}
```

So I was able to find a saloution. It's not perfect but for not it works. If anybody knows a better way to do this feel free posting it.

Here's my code:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

DBHelper myDb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main2);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    myDb = new DBHelper(this);

    //populate an ArrayList<String> from the database and then view it
    ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor data = myDb.getAllData();
    if(data.getCount() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "There are no contents in this list!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        while(data.moveToNext()){
            final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            buffer.append("id: " + data.getString(0) + "\n");
            theList.add(data.getString(1));
            ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,theList);
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    int i = 0;

                    final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
                    while (res.moveToNext()) {


                        if (position == i) {
                            buffer.append("Url: " + res.getString(1) + "\n");
                            buffer.append("Name: " + res.getString(2) + "\n");
                            showMessage("Data", buffer.toString());

                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    //Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,buffer,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }
}

public void showMessage(String title,String Message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(Message);
    builder.show();
}
}
```

Comment: add Toast and check that value

Comment: The response is empty

Comment: perhaps no value in `res` ?

Comment: There are something wrong in this line `myDb.getSingleData(buffer.toString());`. `buffer.toString()` obviously is null.

Comment: Yeah, seems like it... I've changed `Cursor res = myDb.getSingleData(buffer.toString());` to `Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();` and now it shows all items data in that alert. OK thanks for pointing that out. Maybe any ideas how can I fix it?

Comment: What value you want to pass to `getSingleData()` ?

Comment: Well since in `ListView` I am showing urls I should probably pass an `url`, and then when I click on it, it should open an `AlerDialog`? Or is it better to pass an Id? Sorry I'm new to programming

Comment: I would suggest you to pass the ID

Comment: How could I pass it in my situation?

Comment: What will you get for `data.getString(2)` ? Is it url ?

Comment: If I put it in `theList.add(data.getString(1));`? APP crashes. But logically 0 should be id. 1 should be url. 2 should be name.

Comment: Before that no crash , now crash ? @.@

Comment: Yeah for some reason it works with `data.getString(0)`: shows id and `data.getString(1)`: shows urls. `data.getString(2)`: crashes the app

Comment: It might be because some `data.getString(2)` are null

Comment: what if you try this  `Cursor res = myDb.getSingleData(data.getString(1));`

Comment: I have tried this one... crashes the app, when I click on a item

Comment: I was able to do it... It's more like a bad programming than a fix but it works. Thank for the help. See my edit if you want to know how I did it